# Checking for duplicate values

Tags: php

I'm building a form via a loop outputting values inside some text fields. I need to check and see if there are any duplicate values. I think I need to also place the values into an array and check against it on every output.

```
$duplicates = array();
$has_duplicate = false;

foreach ($vals AS $v) {

   if (in_array($v->val, $duplicates)) {
      $has_duplicate = true;
   }

   echo '<input type="text" value="'.$v->val.'" class="'.($has_duplicate ? 'dupe' : '').'">';

   $duplicates[$v->val] = true;       
}
```

Something like this?

Comment: Where does the data come from, it may be better to fix duplication before it happens.  IF that is not possible you can use a combination of `array_column` and `array_count_values`  (or array_column, and array_unique, array_diff) but  I would need to see said array to be of more help.

Comment: You can use `count(array_unique(array_column($vals, 'val')))`. If this is the same as `count($vals)` then there are no duplicates.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Yes something like that. And actually the code itself.

Comment: If you're going to do it that way, you should set `$has_duplicate = false;` _inside_ the loop. Otherwise it will keep its `true` value from the previous iteration.

Comment: Note that this form of `array_column` will only work in PHP 7. In PHP 5 it can only be used for arrays of arrays, not arrays of objects.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Once there's a duplicate found, it always has duplicates.

Comment: @Barmar it will mark the next value in `$vals` as `$has_duplicate` even if that value doesn't have a duplicate. The `$has_duplicate` switch never gets flipped back off.

Comment: OP's raising a flag. Do not mind the variable names. All values should have a corresponding `key` in `$duplicates`. Even the below answer is wrong. The code works well for OP.

Comment: I mean, that `$has_duplicate` doesn't look like it's supposed to apply to the whole set, but to the specific value, since it determines the class on the input for that value.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I didn't notice that he was using the variable in the `echo` statement, I thought it was just a global flag saying if any duplicates were found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you want to mark *all* the values that have a duplicate, you'll need to iterate `$vals` twice. Otherwise, the first instance of a value that appears multiple times won't be marked as a duplicate because it can't be determined that it's duplicated until that value is encountered again.

```
foreach ($vals as $v) {
    if (isset($unique[$v->val])) $duplicates[$v->val] = true;
    $unique[$v->val] = true;
}

foreach ($vals as $v) {
    $class = isset($duplicate[$v->val]) ? 'dupe' : '';
    echo '<input type="text" value="'. $v->val .'" class="'. $class .'">';
}
```

---

If you only want to mark subsequent instances of a value with the `dupe` class, one loop will do

```
foreach ($vals as $v) {
    $class = isset($unique[$v->val]) ? 'dupe' : '';
    echo '<input type="text" value="'.$v->val.'" class="'. $class .'">' . "\n";
    $unique[$v->val] = true;
}
```

Comment: That's a good point, (I was in a bit of a rush ... lol ... leaving work in about 10 min)

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix well, I'm not certain that is what's wanted. But I think for people who find this Q&A later, it could go either way.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I see the problem:

```
foreach ($vals AS $v) {
   if (in_array($v->val, $duplicates)) {
      $has_duplicate = true;
   }

$duplicates[$v->val] = true;
```

You need to check `isset` for example:

```
foreach ($vals AS $v) {
    $has_duplicate = false; //reset on each iteration of the loop
    if (isset($duplicates[$v->val])) {
         $has_duplicate = true;
    }
....
```

The issue is `in_array` looks in the `values` and your setting all the values to `true`, you need to check the keys (`$duplicates[$v->val] = true;`) which is where you are putting your data.

You can also use `array_key_exists()` to check, but no one uses that thing, as it's slower then isset.

> **in_array** — Checks if a value exists in an array
>
> bool **in_array** ( mixed **$needle** , array **$haystack** [, bool **$strict** = FALSE ] )

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Something I have done more times then I care to admit.

**UPDATE**

A better way to write this is to just do away with the local variable, as it's not really needed (unless there is other places its used, not included in the question)

```
foreach ($vals AS $v) {
  echo '<input type="text" value="'.$v->val.'" class="'.(isset($duplicates[$v->val]) ? 'dupe' : '').'">';
  $duplicates[$v->val] = true;       
}
```

It doesn't really make a difference if you set this multiple times `$duplicates[$v->val] = true;` as True is True.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to reset `$has_duplicate` each time through the loop, not keep its value from the previous iteration. So you can simply do:

```
$has_duplicate = isset($duplicates[$v->val]);
```